# Dynamic loading of Python C extension fails due to missing symbols

Tags: python, c, plugins, shared-libraries, dynamic-loading

I am in the situation that I have an executable (`main.c`) that dynamically loads a shared object (`py_plugin.c`) which is in turn is linked to python.

However, when the python plugin attempts to import a module whose  dependencies are **not** linked to libpython I get the following error:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/bz2.x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyExc_SystemError
```

As far as I can deduce this implies that the library `bz2.x86_64-linux-gnu.so` does not have access to the python symbols.

Note that the error is specific to the "bz2" package because I am forcing it to surface using the minimal working example at the end of the question. There I am performing an explicit import of the "bz2", which loads the library `bz2.x86_64-linux-gnu.so`, inside the python plugin (`py_plugin.c`).

Looking at the dependencies I verify that:

1. The library `bz2.x86_64-linux-gnu.so` is **not** linked to python

   ```
       usr@cmptr $ ldd /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/bz2.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
       linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd511fb000)
       libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8c63a0a000)
       libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8c6362a000)
       libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007f8c6341a000)
       /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8c63e33000)
   ```
2. But my python plugin **is**:

   ```
       usr@cmptr $ ldd py_plugin.so
       linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc1ef5c000)
       libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f56ac01c000)
       libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f56abc3c000)
       libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f56aba1d000)
       libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f56ab800000)
       libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f56ab5fc000)
       libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f56ab3f8000)
       libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f56ab0a2000)
       /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f56ac79a000)
   ```

#### My questions are the following:

1. The problem itself is quite obvious, but why is the python symbols not available when my plugin clearly is linked to libpython?
2. Does anyone have an idea for how to resolve this issue when I can **not** link python to the main executable (it is a pre-compiled binary)?

From [this e-mail thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/distutils-sig@python.org/msg23796.html) I understand that the source of the error may be because differences in the distribution philosophy of python (I am running a Ubuntu-based distro). This [bug report](https://bugs.python.org/msg18810) also highlights the issue.

---

#### Example producing error

**generate libs/execs**

```
gcc $(pkg-config --cflags python) -shared -o py_plugin.so py_plugin.c $(pkg-config --libs python)
gcc -o main main.c -lltdl
```

The putput from pkg-config on my system is:

```
pkg-config --cflags python
-I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7

pkg-config --libs python
-lpython
```

**file:** main.c

```
#include <ltdl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int(*dyn_fptr)();

int main()
{
  if(lt_dlinit()) {
    return -1;
  }

  lt_dlhandle handle = lt_dlopen("./py_plugin.so");

  dyn_fptr func = (dyn_fptr)lt_dlsym(handle, "func");
  int a = func(); // <----------------------------------- Call "func" in py_plugin

  lt_dlclose(handle);
  return 0;
}
```

**file:** `py_plugin.c`

```
#include <Python.h>

int func()
{

  Py_Initialize();
  PyObject *pName = PyString_FromString("bz2");

  PyObject *pModule = PyImport_Import(pName); // <--------------------- ERROR
  Py_DECREF(pName);

  if(!pModule) {
    PyErr_Print();
  }

  Py_Finalize();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps, the problem is as simple as the forum you linked too says. Debian and distros derived from it often break LSB and then everything is layed out differently and in a unexpected way. But I am curious! Why are you calling a python plugin from c?

Comment: Also, what happens if you `import bz2` directly from a python script?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi when I simply import "bz2" everything works fine since the python executable is (statically) linked to libpython and the module consequently get access to the symbols directly from the executable.



As to "why python from C?" The C library is designed for portability between (scientific) applications and we use python to perform typically dynamic tasks. Think of the data in C mapping itself into a Python object whenever it wants to do something "fancy".

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi You are quite right that the issue is simply Debian-specific, Fedora handles this as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing the thread for future reference.

As was pointed out in the comment to my question the problem here is that Python is (currently) packaged differently on different Linux distributions.

In order to fix the issue one must ensure that the Python symbols are visible to libraries that are loaded *within the python plugin*.

As far as I can tell there are three ways of dealing with it:

1. Link the main executable to Python.
2. Set the `RTDL_GLOBAL` option (only possible when using dlopen, `dlopen("lib.so", RTDL_NOW | RTDL_LAZY | RTDL_GLOBAL)`, and is not guaranteed to be supported on all systems).
3. Set the environment variable `LD_PRELOAD`, `export LD_PRELOAD="/path/to/libpython2.7.so.1.0"`, to enforce certain libraries to be loaded **before** any other library. For me this worked for my little example plugin, but caused harmful interactions when dealing with a larger software framework.